# Flutter-Dart Firebase Get a Summe from Docs

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I wanna get a Summe from Firebase with Flutter-Dart, i can with Stream Builder all Datas receiving but i wanna get a Summe-Total from Orders. For Example how much money did i earn for this month ? or How much money i have to Pay to my Owner ? My Firebase Database look like this,
[Firebase Struktur][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5zsM.png

I wanna get the Grand Total for all "betrag", i tried this like it , but its coming a null, how can i all Documents as List with choosed Feld with For Loop Grand total Calculating and show in the Text ?

```
  var rechnungider = 0;
  firestoreInstance.collection("rechnungen").doc().get().then((value) {
    for (int i = value.data()!.length; i > value.data()!.length; i++) {
      print(value.data());
      rechnungider += int.parse(value.data()!["betrag"]);
    }
    box.write("rechnunggider", rechnungider.toString());
    print("Rechnunggider Yenilendi:${box.read("rechnunggider")}");
    //print(value.data.toString());
  });
}
```

I wanna show without Document name, i mean all betrag data from all Documents.Total Value, Summe.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not calculate the sum of collections on the frontend. I can't warn you enough!

I would recommend to create a cloud function that saves the `sum` on another place in your database. It is the recommended approach for getting the `sum` for a value from a collection.

Let me know if you need an example for the functions to write.

Comment: Hey Tarik ! Thanks for your Answer im glad to u, can u send me an Example about that Function ? Regards,Berkay

Comment: and i found Somethink about the Firebase Documentation, but its not wrote with Flutter or Dart, have u got a Link about the Flutter-Firebase Integration with Queries or Sum Functions ? MFG,.Berkay
[link] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation

Comment: That is a very acurate example. All firebase cloud functions are written in the same language: JavaScript or TypeScript. Just make sure to use the cloud functions solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#solution_cloud_functions

Comment: i didnt found enough Information about the Cloud , can u give me an Example here as Code ? Thanks Tarik, MFG

Comment: Here is an example of a counter when a new user is created: https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/blob/master/packages/rmw-shell/cra-template-rmw/template/functions/auth/onCreate.f.js Have you ever used the cloud functions?

Comment: Hi Tarik , no I didnt use the Cloud Functions and I'm new at this Position , I'm writing some apps with Flutter and I think it's a Experience Area as Cloud Functions , I have to look and learn how can I as Function Programming the Cloud , this is wonderful if I do it, I look up your project.